# RxJS nested subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

Is it possible to avoid ***nested subscribe*** in the following code?

```
this.requestService().subscribe(
      () => this.success(),
      error => {
        const errorDescription = {
          one: 5,
          two: 10
        };
        return this.error(errorDescription).subscribe();
      }
    );
```

The second `subscribe` is part of the error callback of the Observer. How could we use e.g. `switchMap` as to have only one subscribe?

Comment: can you please share the code of `this.error()` function?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need a [`catchError`](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/catch/), that will let you substitute an error with another stream. Though we'll have to update successful result handling:

```js
this.requestService().pipe(

  // handle success value
  tap(() => this.success()),

  // when an error happens
  catchError(error => {
    const errorDescription = {
      one: 5,
      two: 10
    };

    // we switch to `this.error` stream
    return this.error(errorDescription);
  })
).subscribe(value=>{
  // ...here you'll receive both:
  // events from the requestService()
  // and events from this.error(errorDescription)
});
```

Heres an article with detailed overview of [error handling in RxJS](https://medium.com/@kddsky/error-handling-in-rxjs-bac0f96a7def)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea to avoid a 'nested' subscribe. With the code you provided, this is the best I can come up with. If you have any questions, let me know and I'll help.

```
import { of, throwError } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, switchMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';


// this.requestService().subscribe(
//       () => this.success(),
//       error => {
//         const errorDescription = {
//           one: 5,
//           two: 10
//         };
//         return this.error(errorDescription).subscribe();
//       }
//     );

const error = throwError('oops');
const success = of('success!');
const handleError = (d) => of({one: 5, two: 10}).pipe(
  map(n => n),
  catchError(e => 'could not do 2nd network request')
);

const requestServiceSuccess = success.pipe(
  switchMap(d => of(d)),
  catchError(handleError)
)

const requestServiceFail = error.pipe(
  switchMap(d => of(d)),
  catchError(handleError)
)

// if your first network request succeeds, then you will see success
requestServiceSuccess.subscribe(
  (d) => console.log(d),
  (e) => console.log(e)
)
// if your first network request fails, then you will see your errorDescription
requestServiceFail.subscribe(
  (d) => console.log(d),
  (e) => console.log(e)
)
```

You can paste this into stackblitz to check the logs

https://stackblitz.com/fork/rxjs?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: Two subscriptions will likely cause two requests, you need to be careful here. With `of('success')` you wont notice, but try adding `of('success').pipe(tap(console.log))`. Its considered a good practice to have one or even **zero subscriptions** in your code (zero subscriptions can be achieved using e.g. `| async` pipe in angular or out-of-the box with redux epics).

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it like this:

```
this.requestService().pipe(catchError(e => {
  const errorDescription = {
      one: 5,
      two: 10
  };
  return this.error(errorDescription).pipe(switchMap(empty())); 
  // the switch to empty will prevent the error going to success
  // consider moving this into the error handler itself.
})).subscribe(
  () => this.success(),
  error => {
    //should never get here.
  }
);
```

the catchError -> switchMap -> empty is a pattern that appears pretty frequently in my code as my error handlers should stop the processing chain more often than not.